# ADA locked with assets

Tags: nft, transaction, yoroi

Can you send just NFTs and the transaction fee or do you always need to send ADA in a transaction. Also is there a way to unlink the ADA and Asset in the receiver wallet?

Answer (score 1):

To make a transaction on the blockchain you will need to pay a transaction fee of ~0.17 Ada (may change) to the block producer

There is also minimum Ada that needs to be sent to the receiving wallet:

- 1 Ada
- or ~1.5 Ada for NFTs

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the `minUtxoValue` which is a protocol parameter that prevents malicious growth of the UTXO set.

For each new UTXO you create, it needs to have that value (around 1 ADA or so). There is no way to create an UTXO just with native assets.

Answer (score 0):

Recover Any $ADA ‘locked’ with any cnft https://link.medium.com/YbyZABPNepb
$ADA #Cardano

Comment: Take a look at the help regarding referencing external sources to see how to improve this.  https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/referencing